# Need explaination of dmesg(Ubuntu Server)

Tags: server, dmesg

I just set up an old machine I have as an Ubuntu server. When it was booting a huge dmesg came up, and I am not sure what to make of it.

Here is the dmesg file:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12895065/

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: Replaced the faulty hard drive that was causing this, luckily there was nothing on it.

Comment: It appears that you have a hardware problem: "ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }" likely indicates a bad cable or drive as the error indicates drive not ready. Have you checked the smart status of the drive? `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sxy` where sxy is the device on port ata4

Comment: This line:` [   55.345842] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE` might be time to back up /dev/sdc